# Orthogonal Latin squares - Origin of the word "Orthogonal"

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics

Is there any linear-algebraic link with the use of the word "orthogonal" in orthogonal latin squares? I thought about it a little bit and the closest I got to linear algebra was this definition : if $V = \langle v_1,\dots,v_n \rangle_{\mathbb R}$ is an $\mathbb R$-vector space of dimension $n$, a Latin square of order $n$ is a linear map $f : V^2 \to V$ which maps $f(v_i,v_j)$ to $v_{f^*(i,j)}$ where $f^* : [n] \times [n] \to [n]$ is a Latin square in the classical sense (i.e. assigns to a coordinate of an $n \times n$ grid an integer between $1$ and $n$). Then, if we translate the classical definition, two Latin squares $f,g : V^2 \to V$ are orthogonal if $f \times g : V^2 \to V^2$ defined by $(v_i,v_j) \mapsto (f(v_i,v_j),g(v_i,v_j))$ is an isomorphism. This was a quite natural attempt, but it does not seem to involve orthogonality.

(In other words, all I did was replace the occurences of $[n]$ by the $\mathbb R$-vector space it generates, and the rest is just translation.)

Anyone knows the origin of this choice of words, and if yes, is there a link with linear algebra?

Comment: The idea is that you can do a *decomposition* into orthogonal squares by splitting into separate Greek and Latin squares.

Comment: I do't know what's true, but I have thought that in the context of Latin squares "orthogonal" means roughly the same as "strongly independent". A traditional use of Latin squares has been in testing, and if you base tests on two orthogonal Latin squares you make the tests as independent as they can be.

Comment: @oldrinb : You have not understood my question. I totally understand the definition of orthogonal latin squares, I'm asking if there is a link of the choice of words with linear algebra.

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen : So you're saying the choice of words has nothing to do with linear algebra, but rather this feeling of orthogonality that says "no relations between two orthogonal things" as in linear independence?

Comment: That's how I feel, but I know next to nothing about the history of MOLS, so I'm not sure.